# Are protected members part of the public API?

Tags: oop, language-agnostic, protected

Since protected members can be accessed by subclasses, are they part of the public API? Do they therefore share the same backwards compatibility requirements as explicitly public members?

I guess the question becomes more complicated with things like `private[foo]` (from e.g. Scala). Feel free to either answer this bit or not.

Comment: Do (or can) people *use* your objects by subclassing them? If so, then the protected attributes are effectively public; changing the protected API would break other people's code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and yes: protected members are part of the exported (public) API and share the same compatibility requirements.

Java included access modifiers as a precursor to numerous JVM and non-JVM languages that followed in its footsteps; and *Effective Java* has an authoritative statement on the matter.

From *Item 15: Minimize the Accessibility of Classes and Members*,

> ...both private and package-private members are part of a class’s implementation and do not normally impact its exported API.
>
> For members of public classes, a huge increase in accessibility occurs when the access level goes from package-private to protected. A protected member is part of the class’s exported API and must be supported forever. Also, a protected member of an exported class represents a public commitment to an implementation detail. The need for protected members should be relatively rare.